# MongoDB returning wrong row

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I use int64s as a primary key and when i query for some, it returns a row with a different int64 as the key.

When i query:

```
{
 _id: NumberLong("76561198346292536")
}
```

or

```
{
 _id: 76561198346292536)
}
```

the query that seems to get sent is:

```
{
 _id: 76561198346292540
}
```

and the row returned has a primary key of `76561198346292544`

I am using int64s as a user ID so it's pretty important this basic query works.

I have seen this happen in Go, but the same happens in MongoDB Compass:

### [image]

I *think* it may be due to the fact JS does not have int64s, so it becomes a float64 and some accuracy is lost as some bits are needed for the decimal. If this is correct, is there a way to handle this?

Thanks!

Thanks.

Comment: FYI this is reproducible in any JS environment. Just open the console in your browser and try `let foo = 76561198346292536` You'll see it set to `76561198346292540`.